# Eliminating shadow outlines from an object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm looking for ideas to help improve my current approach for real-time object detection using computer vision (specifically the opencv library).  My goal is to accurately detect a golf-ball through image processing in a large variety of environments/lighting conditions.  My detection process works quite well probably 80% of the time, but I'm hitting edge cases that cause failures that I can't ignore.  The edge case I'm focusing on right now is extreme shadows being cast by the golf-ball.  Here is a pair of example images.  The coloured image is my source, and the black and white image is my post-processed result.

[image: source] [image: processed]

There are a few important variables to consider with my application

- Source coming from a video feed, and being processed in real-time
- It can be windy, so camera shake can be an issue
- Camera isn't guaranteed to be incredible quality, so need to account for extra noise/not incredible resolution

I won't go into full details in the processing I'm doing to detect moving objects (Kalman Filter, Background Subtraction, ...) as in this specific example I'm failing to detect a stationary object (ie. ball has gone to rest).

1. Grab initial frame before any balls are in-frame as my base frame (this will be used for background subtraction)
2. convert image to greyscale
3. apply a median blur to eliminate noise, which can otherwise be pretty extreme due to a combination of camera shake, poor camera quality
4. apply an adaptive threshold on the image.  I'm using ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GUASSIAN_C and have been tuning the block size and C constant values as best I can
5. apply background subtraction (I'm using the built-in CNT Subtractor)
6. Apply a small dilation kernel to the entire image to try and increase the size of the contours that are left after the above processing, as they can sometimes become quite small after the blur filter for example
7. use opencv's "findContours" with RETR_TREE, and CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE parameters
8. walk the contour hierarchy, looking for "filled in" contours.  The idea being that the golf-balls should mostly be completely filled in, compared to other objects which will have an outline, and I can use the hierarchy to determine which contours are filled in or not (ie do they have child contours)
9. for each filled in contour, do an enclosing circle.  Compare area of enclosing circle to contour area, filter by an acceptable difference to determine how circular the object is
10. another pass, filtering by min/max area size since I can assume the camera will always be at a similar height to "hone-in" on the object

As you can see from the images above, this approach runs into problems when the ball itself has a lot of contrast due to shadows.  To me it looks like the adaptive threshold pass is filtering out the darker part of the ball (due to shadow) which creates a non-circular shape.  Perhaps I need to dial in the adaptive threshhold pass to allow for a bit more contrast since we can assume shadows are always on the dark side and a ground shadow should be darker than the shaded part of the ball?  I'd also like to completely eliminate the leftover outline of the ground-shadow if possible.  My guess is that the edges of the shadow being slightly lighter is the reason they don't get filtered out by my adaptive threshold pass.  Open to any and all suggestions :-)

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I think the images above are a pretty good example.  If you look at the ball in the coloured image, you can see that half the ball is quite a bit darker than the other half, and more closely matches the colour of the shadow it is casting.  The black and white image is the result of my processing.